# StyleCop for other languages

Tags: coding-style, stylecop

weve been using StyleCop for enforcing coding standards in C#, I was wondering are there similar tools for other languages? namely:

- js
- css
- sql

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202887/stylecop-equivalent-for-sql-server

Answer (score 8):

Haven't seen StyleCop, but for Java there is Checkstyle: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript: [JSHint](http://jshint.com/)

CSS: [CSS LINT](http://csslint.net/)

SQL: Sonar

Answer (score 1):

There has been some moves towards CSS & JS coding standards being supported in [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer) ([blog post/announcement](http://gregsherwood.blogspot.com/2008/10/phpcodesniffer-csscodesniffer.html)). It's currently (March 2009) in Release Candidate status though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any js tool that will actually enforce rules on commit but http://www.jslint.com/ is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

For Perl there is a tool called `perlcritic`.