# StyleCop equivalent for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, coding-style, stylecop

Is there any tools like [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) for SQL Server?
We need the same features of StyleCop (enforce a set of style and consistency rules).

[Additional Feature]: Integration with SQLServer Management Studio would be cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is SSW's [SQLAuditor](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/SQLAuditor/)

[There's also the [SQL Server 2008 R2 Best Practices Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0FD439D7-4BFF-4DF7-A52F-9A1BE8725591&displaylang=en&displaylang=en) but that has more of a DBA focus]